# Who were the priests?

Tags: exodus

In Exodus 19:22 (NASB)

> Also have the priests who approach the Lord consecrate themselves, or else the Lord will break out against them.

Who were the priests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that the passage of Ex 19-23 describes the establishment of the Israelite covenant which never mentions a formal priesthood.  That had to wait until the levitical covenant was established as per Lev 1-9, 16, 21-27 , Num 3, 4, 8, 18, 25:10-13, Deut 33:8-11; see also Neh 13:29, Mal 2:4-8, Num 25:12, 13, Ps 106:30, Num 18:19.

However, we note that priests had discharged priestly functions previously such as:

- Melchizedek, Gen 14:18
- Jethro, Ex 2:16, 3:1, 18:1

So, what are we to make of Ex 19:22 - who were the priests?  It was not the entire nation of Israel as per Ex 19:6 but possibly the appointed priest of each family as implied in Ex 24:5.

Ellicott suggests this:

> (22) The priests.—This has been called an anachronism, since the
> Levitical priesthood was not as yet instituted. But the Israelites,
> like all other ancient tribes or races, must have had priests long ere
> this, appointed upon one principle or another. It is a reasonable
> conjecture that hitherto the heads of families had exercised
> sacerdotal functions.

The Pulpit Commentary has a similar suggestion:

> Verse 22. - Let the priests also. It has been objected, that no
> priests had been as yet appointed, and that we have here therefore an
> anachronism. But every nation in ancient times had priests, appointed
> on one principle or another: and **the Levitical priesthood must be
> regarded as having superseded one previously existent**, not as the
> first priesthood known to Israel. We have a second mention of priests,
> previous to the appointment of Aaron's sons to the office (in Exodus
> 24:5), which confirms the present passage.

Barnes also reaches the same conclusion

> The priests also - Sacrifices had hitherto been offered by firstborn,
> or the heads of families.